# how to make puppetserver work for non-root user

Tags: puppet

I am installing puppet 6 on centos 7.4:

```
$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core) 

$ uname -a
Linux centos7-puppetmaster-vm.test.org 3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Mar 7 19:03:37 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ rpm -qa | grep puppetserver
puppetserver-6.0.2-1.el7.noarch

# netstat -tupln | grep 8140
tcp6       0      0 :::8140                 :::*                    LISTEN      3398/java
```

If I run as root

```
# puppetserver ca list
```

it does not throw error but if I run same command as non root user I get

```
$ /opt/puppetlabs/bin/puppetserver ca list
Traceback (most recent call last):
    12: from /opt/puppetlabs/server/apps/puppetserver/cli/apps/ca:5:in `<main>'
    11: from /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_gems/gems/puppetserver-ca-1.1.2/lib/puppetserver/ca/cli.rb:89:in `run'
    10: from /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_gems/gems/puppetserver-ca-1.1.2/lib/puppetserver/ca/action/list.rb:60:in `run'
     9: from /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_gems/gems/puppetserver-ca-1.1.2/lib/puppetserver/ca/action/list.rb:117:in `get_all_certs'
     8: from /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_gems/gems/puppetserver-ca-1.1.2/lib/puppetserver/ca/certificate_authority.rb:215:in `get_certificate_statuses'
     7: from /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_gems/gems/puppetserver-ca-1.1.2/lib/puppetserver/ca/certificate_authority.rb:253:in `get'
     6: from /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_gems/gems/puppetserver-ca-1.1.2/lib/puppetserver/ca/utils/http_client.rb:49:in `with_connection'
     5: from /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/http.rb:609:in `start'
     4: from /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/http.rb:909:in `start'
     3: from /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/http.rb:920:in `do_start'
     2: from /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/http.rb:981:in `connect'
     1: from /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/protocol.rb:44:in `ssl_socket_connect'
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/protocol.rb:44:in `connect_nonblock': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (unable to get local issuer certificate) (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
```

Comment: another interesting point noticed is, I copied /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl to ~/.puppetlabs/etc/puppet. This problem fixed. But still not clear why puppetserver generated different certificates?

Comment: Try running 
puppetserver ca list --config /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/puppet.conf
This appears to work for me in PuppetServer version 5.3

Answer (score 0):

Try running 
`puppetserver ca list --config /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/puppet.conf`

In your /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/puppet.conf, make sure you have the following line

`confdir =  /etc/puppetlabs/puppet`

You could add just ssldir like below but the above helps on a more global level as all the confs are described.

`ssldir =  /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl`

See [Puppet Confs](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/configuration.html#caport) for all available options.